# How to use sed/grep to extract text between two words with condition?

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed, extract

how i can extract just an online CLine (with status_icon_online)? i can extract all clines by doing :

```
cat test.txt | sed -n 's:.*">C\(.*\)</a>.*:\1:p'
```

but i want just the online ones, the result should be like this:

> C: free.cccamlux.co 21900 FREEAC5p08w cccamlux.com

my test.txt file:

```
> <tr>
<td valign="middle">
<a href="/info/CCcam/free.cccamlux.co_21900_FREEAC5p08w_cccamlux.com/75e56a5655a02b839664981da2f69445937f6bbf" title="View line details for free Cline C: free.cccamlux.co 21900 FREEAC5p08w cccamlux.com">C: free.cccamlux.co 21900 FREEAC5p08w cccamlux.com</a>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
<span class="span_tooltip glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign status_icon_online" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="CCcam server down or invalid cline credentials"></span>
</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="/info/CCcam/free.cccamlux.co_21900_FREEAC5p08w_cccamlux.com/75e56a5655a02b839664981da2f69445937f6bbf">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cred btn-sm btn btn-default">Show</button>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="middle">
<a href="/info/CCcam/palacio.iptv.re_1122_uxftgm1p_palacio/c3dbaa129dccbff15eeb7e4d6cd7d7210df38099" title="View line details for free Cline C: palacio.iptv.re 1122 uxftgm1p palacio">C: palacio.iptv.re 1122 uxftgm1p palacio</a>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
<span class="span_tooltip glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign status_icon_offline" data-toggle="tooltip" rel="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="CCcam server down or invalid cline credentials"></span>
</td>
<td align="center" valign="middle">
<a href="/info/CCcam/palacio.iptv.re_1122_uxftgm1p_palacio/c3dbaa129dccbff15eeb7e4d6cd7d7210df38099">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-cred btn-sm btn btn-default">Show</button>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: use `grep` instead of `sed` ..... try with `cat test.txt | grep -o '">C\(.*\)</a>'`

Comment: It is totally unclear what you are asking. Please explain terms like "online CLine".

Comment: The answer below  is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this;

```
 awk '/<tr>/ {printf "\n%s\n",$0;next} {printf "%s ",$0}' test |  grep -o -P '(?<=Cline).*(?=online)'  |  grep -o -P '.*(?=">C)'
```

awk command; merge lines between `<tr>` and `</tr>` in your file.

first grep ; get text only between Cline and online

last grep ; get only url parts

Test;

```
$ awk '/<tr>/ {printf "\n%s\n",$0;next} {printf "%s ",$0}' test |  grep -o -P '(?<=Cline).*(?=online)'  |  grep -o -P '.*(?=">C)'
C: free.cccamlux.co 21900 FREEAC5p08w cccamlux.com
```